# In WPF I can create scatterplots?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts, scatter-plot

I can create scatter plots in wpf ?? I have failed, I would like to create one image (the image was created in Exel)

[image: Scatter]

Comment: not a dupe but shows and example with OxyPlot library: [Oxyplot Scatter Series InvalidatePlot(true) not working in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586553/oxyplot-scatter-series-invalidateplottrue-not-working-in-wpf)

Comment: @ASh Your contribution is great, did not know the library and apparently is more complete than I have seen.

Comment: @ASh but any version of oxyplot is stable, you know each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution with oxyplot, I do so.

```
var grafica = new PlotModel { LegendPosition = LegendPosition.TopRight };

            var functionSeries1 = new FunctionSeries { Title = "Clase de Exactitud" };
            functionSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 1.2));
            functionSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 1.2));
            functionSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(8, 1.2));
            functionSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(12, 1.2));
            functionSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(20, 1.2));
            functionSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(29.99, 1.2));
            grafica.Series.Add(functionSeries1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DevExpress Components [Sample diagram](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4691)

Comment: Hi, I have received but not scatterplot.